# Convert output of Image Segmentation/Classification (From land-use classification) into different shapefiles

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, classification, land-use

I am performing the Landuse Classification on satellite imagery. I have classified my image into different categories.

I have the shapefile of the original image, now I want to create the separate shapefiles for each classified portion in the image.

Is there any way, I can achieve this using GDAL (python)? Or any other library of python.

A sample image is given below:

[image]

Comment: Please state which software you're using and then have a look at something like `select by expression/value`.

Comment: I want to do this using python script using GDAl /GeoPandas or any other library. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html maybe this will work, in arcmap I use raster to polygon, this looks like the equivalent.